# vim output user-defined command to buffer

Tags: vim

I try to create a user-defined command in vim that is supposed to return an uuid.

```
command -range CreateUUID !python3 -c 'import uuid; print(uuid.uuid4())'<cr>
```

The command works but it just outputs to the terminal.

I have tried

- :. CreateUUID
- :% CreateUUID

Answer (score 2):

In VimScript commands never return anything, as they are not even considered as expressions. You must declare a function instead. For example,

```
function! UUID() abort
    python3 import uuid
    return py3eval('str(uuid.uuid4())')
endfunction

:put =UUID()
```

An alternative is to capture the command's output by using a specialized function like `execute()` (for an Ex command) or `system()` (for an external tool):

```
:put =system('uuidgen')
```

Yet another thing is "read-space-bang" command (`:h :r!`), so you can do

```
:r !python3 -c 'import uuid; print(uuid.uuid4())'
```

But, 1) again, it only inserts an external tool's stdout, not an Ex-command's output; 2) it's not the way to compose two arbitrary Ex-commands, as "read-space-bang" counts as a single command with a very unique syntax.